# Multiple statements in one SQL-query, or use Batch?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, batch-file

I'm sending a long list of updates to a database from a Java-program. I'm wondering if there's a speed difference between

- Putting all the updates in one query and execute that
- Making a preparedStatement, adding every update to the batch and executing the batch

Comment: Which RDBMS? If it's Oracle you could use bulk collect for an even quicker and more kind way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Using PreparedStatement and batching would be the preferred approach. It reduces the network traffic between the client and the database server.

Comment: I'm not sending the updates one by one. I'm wondering whether putting all the updates in one String (seperated by a ; )  would be faster

Comment: Even if you are sending all statements in one call, batching of PreparedStatement improves performance on 2 counts - 1. the SQL of the statement is sent to the database server only once. So that saves network traffic  2. The prepared statement handle is reused on the database server. So the cost of processing SQL is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does!
It will reduce the traffic between application and server.

I know you mentioned java but just as an example, this is a hint from a C# book Im reading :

```
NOTE FREE PERFORMANCE UPGRADE!
Setting UpdateBatchSize to 0 is a quick way to boost the update performance of the
DbDataAdapter object. (Setting the value to 0 instructs the DbDataAdapter object to create the largest possible batch size for changes)
```

Comment: either way I'm only sending data to the server once.

Comment: so I didnt understand the question, can you post the actual queries you are thinking?